# Druid ingestion problem - memory allocation

Tags: druid

I am having issues on the ingestion side.
I have around 290,000 segments.
After a few days of perfect ingestion processing, Druid starts failing ingesting.
The errors I am getting are:

> GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1588944K->210544K(1736192K)]
> 2383728K->1021504K(2595328K), 0.0384942 secs] [Times: user=0.81
> sys=0.03, real=0.04 secs] [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen:
> 210544K->76192K(1736192K)] [ParOldGen: 810960K->858732K(2012160K)]
> 1021504K->934924K(3748352K), [Metaspace: 91328K->91306K(1132544K)],
> 0.7209968 secs] [Times: user=17.12 sys=0.90, real=0.72 secs] [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1461664K->84288K(1727488K)]
> 2320396K->948612K(3739648K), 0.0516311 secs] [Times: user=1.31
> sys=0.05, real=0.05 secs] [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen:
> 1469760K->90160K(1751040K)] 2334084K->960068K(3763200K), 0.0242025
> secs] [Times: user=0.41 sys=0.08, real=0.03 secs] [GC (Allocation
> Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1495600K->93888K(1499648K)]
> 2365508K->969628K(3511808K), 0.0283021 secs] [Times: user=0.53
> sys=0.05, real=0.03 secs] [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen:
> 1499328K->100265K(1754624K)] 2375068K->981617K(3766784K), 0.0258001
> secs] [Times: user=0.46 sys=0.02, real=0.03 secs] [GC (Allocation
> Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1513897K->103760K(1517568K)]
> 2395249K->990416K(3529728K), 0.0244750 secs] [Times: user=0.50
> sys=0.05, real=0.03 secs] [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen:
> 1517392K->111120K(1757696K)] 2404048K->1002608K(3769856K), 0.0281102
> secs] [Times: user=0.60 sys=0.04, real=0.03 secs] [GC (Allocation
> Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1543184K->117936K(1747456K)]
> 2434672K->1014504K(3759616K), 0.0252510 secs] [Times: user=0.60
> sys=0.08, real=0.03 secs] [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen:
> 1550000K->119120K(1770496K)] 2446568K->1021056K(3782656K), 0.0747994
> secs] [Times: user=1.04 sys=0.01, real=0.08 secs] [GC (Allocation
> Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1586512K->127088K(1760256K)]
> 2488448K->1033752K(3772416K), 0.0293217 secs] [Times: user=0.53
> sys=0.24, real=0.02 secs] [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen:
> 1594480K->134816K(1791488K)] 2501144K->1045960K(3803648K), 0.0366369
> secs] [Times: user=0.79 sys=0.05, real=0.04 secs] [GC (Allocation
> Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1648800K->142384K(1781760K)]
> 2559944K->1058048K(3793920K), 0.0445734 secs] [Times: user=0.98
> sys=0.11, real=0.05 secs] [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen:
> 1656368K->146752K(1816576K)] 2572032K->1066928K(3828736K), 0.0641577
> secs] [Times: user=0.86 sys=0.02, real=0.06 secs] [GC (System.gc())
> [PSYoungGen: 273231K->143044K(1807360K)] 1193408K->1067716K(3819520K),
> 0.1127108 secs] [Times: user=0.88 sys=0.00, real=0.11 secs] [Full GC (System.gc()) [PSYoungGen: 143044K->0K(1807360K)] [ParOldGen:
> 924672K->1061214K(2012160K)] 1067716K->1061214K(3819520K), [Metaspace:
> 91350K->91350K(1132544K)], 2.7635234 secs] [Times: user=40.86
> sys=0.43, real=2.76 secs] [GC (System.gc()) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
> warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000007be200000, 9437184, 0)
> failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
>
> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
> Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 9437184 bytes for committing reserved memory.
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
> /opt/druid/hs_err_pid23725.log
>
> 021-08-02 15:57:02,759 main DEBUG
> AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=CACHED [GC (Metadata GC Threshold)
> [PSYoungGen: 193994K->15015K(305664K)] 193994K->15103K(1005056K),
> 0.0359705 secs] [Times: user=0.61 sys=0.12, real=0.04 secs] [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 15015K->0K(305664K)] [ParOldGen:
> 88K->13777K(699392K)] 15103K->13777K(1005056K), [Metaspace:
> 20552K->20552K(1067008K)], 0.0417042 secs] [Times: user=0.71 sys=0.00,
> real=0.04 secs] [GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen:
> 227685K->17760K(397824K)] 241462K->31545K(1097216K), 0.0317489 secs]
> [Times: user=0.55 sys=0.09, real=0.03 secs] [Full GC (Metadata GC
> Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 17760K->0K(397824K)] [ParOldGen:
> 13785K->21057K(699392K)] 31545K->21057K(1097216K), [Metaspace:
> 34143K->34143K(1079296K)], 0.0494124 secs] [Times: user=0.70 sys=0.03,
> real=0.05 secs] [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen:
> 379904K->19134K(542208K)] 400961K->40199K(1241600K), 0.0226037 secs]
> [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] [GC (Metadata GC
> Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 208984K->11023K(580096K)]
> 230049K->32097K(1279488K), 0.0193193 secs] [Times: user=0.27 sys=0.01,
> real=0.02 secs] [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen:
> 11023K->0K(580096K)] [ParOldGen: 21073K->19920K(904192K)]
> 32097K->19920K(1484288K), [Metaspace: 57781K->57781K(1101824K)],
> 0.1619206 secs] [Times: user=3.53 sys=0.03, real=0.16 secs] [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 536576K->39126K(580096K)]
> 556496K->59054K(1484288K), 0.0221522 secs] [Times: user=0.39 sys=0.05,
> real=0.02 secs] [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen:
> 573446K->36851K(705024K)] 593374K->111081K(1609216K), 0.0349221 secs]
> [Times: user=0.91 sys=0.23, real=0.03 secs] Finished peon task Heap
> PSYoungGen      total 705024K, used 437257K [0x0000000740000000,
> 0x0000000773100000, 0x00000007c0000000)   eden space 668160K, 59% used
> [0x0000000740000000,0x00000007587059b8,0x0000000768c80000)   from
> space 36864K, 99% used
> [0x000000076d480000,0x000000076f87ccc0,0x000000076f880000)   to
> space 73728K, 0% used
> [0x0000000768c80000,0x0000000768c80000,0x000000076d480000)  ParOldGen
> total 904192K, used 74230K [0x0000000640000000, 0x0000000677300000,
> 0x0000000740000000)   object space 904192K, 8% used
> [0x0000000640000000,0x000000064487db20,0x0000000677300000)  Metaspace
> used 85948K, capacity 87888K, committed 88064K, reserved 1126400K
> class space    used 10616K, capacity 11184K, committed 11264K,
> reserved 1048576K